# ¿Cómo guardar DATA en 2 SCHEMA diferentes? Nodejs MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, mongodb

Mi intención en el proyecto que estoy realizando es que el usuario cree una publicación que contenga Titulo, Descripción, IMG y Secciones. Estás "SECCIONES" según mi idea, el usuario podrá ir añadiendolas sin límite. Vease como un instructivo, el cual tiene su tema principal y luego vendrian los pasos (secciones en mi caso).

El problema en el que estoy estancado es que estoy usando `Schema.Types.ObjectId` de SECCIONES en mi PUBLICACIONES pero no sé cómo guardar y obtener ese ID al momento de crear/guardar la publicación general ya que son 2 SCHEMA diferentes.

Mi modelo Publicaciones:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const PublicacionSchema = new Schema(
    {
        titulo: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        descripcion: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        grado: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        materia: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        submateria: [{
            type: String,
            required: true
        }],
        seccion: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Seccion', 
            default: []
        }],
        usuario: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'Usuario', 
            default: []
        }],
        img: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    },
    {
        collection: 'publicaciones'
    }
);

PublicacionSchema.method('toJSON', function(){
    const { __v, ...object } = this.toObject();
    return object;
});


module.exports = model('Publicacion', PublicacionSchema);
```

Mi Routes Publicaciones:

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');




//<!-- ============================================================== -->
//<!-- RUTAS CONTROLLERS -->
//<!-- ============================================================== -->
const publicacionesController = require('../controllers/publicaciones');




//<!-- ============================================================== -->
//<!-- IMPORTACIONES DE MIDDLEWARES -->
//<!-- ============================================================== -->
const { validarCampos } = require('../middlewares/validar-campos');
const { validarJWT } = require('../middlewares/validar-jwt');




//<!-- ============================================================== -->
//<!-- VARIABLES -->
//<!-- ============================================================== -->
const router = Router();




//<!-- ============================================================== -->
//<!-- RUTAS GET -->
//<!-- ============================================================== -->
router.get('/publicaciones', 
        validarJWT, 
        publicacionesController.getPublicaciones
);




//<!-- ============================================================== -->
//<!-- RUTAS POST -->
//<!-- ============================================================== -->
router.post('/crear', 
    [
        validarJWT,
        check('titulo', 'El titulo es obligatorio').exists().not().isEmpty(),
        check('descripcion', 'La descripcion es obligatorio').exists().not().isEmpty(),
        check('grado', 'El grado es obligatorio').exists().not().isEmpty(),
        check('materia', 'La materia es obligatorio').exists().not().isEmpty(),
        check('submateria', 'La submateria es obligatorio').exists().not().isEmpty(),
        validarCampos,
    ], 
    publicacionesController.crearPublicacion
);




//<!-- ============================================================== -->
//<!-- RUTAS PUT -->
//<!-- ============================================================== -->
router.put('/publicacion/:id',
    [
        validarJWT,
        check('titulo', 'El titulo es obligatorio').exists().not().isEmpty(),
        validarCampos,
    ], 
    publicacionesController.actualizarPublicacion
);




//<!-- ============================================================== -->
//<!-- RUTAS DELETE -->
//<!-- ============================================================== -->
router.delete('/publicacion/:id', );



module.exports = router;
```

Mi Controllers Publicaciones:

```js
const { response } = require('express');
const PublicacionModel = require('../models/publicacion');
const SeccionModel = require('../models/seccion');


const controller = {
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->
    //<!-- Inicio Mostrar Publicaciones -->
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->
    getPublicaciones: async(req, res = response) => {

        // Variable que guarda las Publicaciones a mostrar
        const publicaciones = await PublicacionModel.find().populate('usuario', 'nombre img');


        res.json({
            ok: true,
            publicaciones,
            id: req.id
        });
    },
     //<!-- ============================================================== -->
    //<!-- Fin Mostrar Publicaciones -->
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->




    //<!-- ============================================================== -->
    //<!-- Inicio Crear Publicación -->
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->
    crearPublicacion: async(req, res = response) => {

        // Obtener DATA de SECCION
        const seccion = new SeccionModel(req.body.seccion);

        
        
        try {
            // Guardar secciones
            const seccionDB = await seccion.save();


            // DATA de USUARIO - DATA de PUBLICACIÓN
            const uid = req.id;
            const publicacion = new PublicacionModel({
                usuario: uid,
                seccion: seccionDB.id,
                ...req.body
            });

        // Guardar publicación
        const publicacionDB = await publicacion.save();
            



            // Respuesta
            res.json({
                ok: true,
                seccion: seccionDB,
                publicacion: publicacionDB,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                msg: 'Error inesperado.... revisar logs'
            });
        }
    },
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->
    //<!-- Fin Crear Publicación -->
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->

}



module.exports = controller;
```

Como se puede observar intenté guardar primero las secciones para tener el ID pero no logré tener éxito.

Mi modelo Secciones:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const SeccionSchema = new Schema(
    {
        titulo: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        descripcion: {
            type: String,
            required: true, 
        },
        img: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    },
    {
        collections: 'secciones'
    }
);

SeccionSchema.method('toJSON', function(){
    const { __v, ...object } = this.toObject();
    return object;
});


module.exports = model('Seccion', SeccionSchema);
```

Así guardo la DATA desde POSTMAN:

```js
{
    "titulo": "Mi primera publicación",
    "descripcion": "Esto es un tema muy extenso.",
    "grado": "Primaria",
    "materia": "Español",
    "submateria": "Arte",
    "seccion": [
        {
            "titulo": "Paso 1",
            "descripcion": "Esto debe tomarse con mucha seriedad."
        }
    ]
}
```